# std::copy contents into vector field under the structure

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

I am trying to optimize my code to use vector instead of array to get rid of malloc and memcpy

Here is my old code:

```
typedef struct {
    double param1, param2;   // 1x1
    double* arr1, arr2;      // 1xN
}myStruct

myStruct* readData;
char* buf, bp; 
int i;
// SKipped code load in external file contents into buf...
int ArraySize = 60;   // this will change
int StructSize = 3000; // this will change
for (i = 0; i < StructSize; i++){
  readData[i].arr1= (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * ArraySize );
  readData[i].arr2= (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * ArraySize );
}
bp = buf;
for (i = 0; i < StructSize; i++){
  memcpy((void*)&readData[i].Param1, (void*)bp, sizeof(double)); bp += sizeof(double);
  memcpy((void*)&readData[i].Param2, (void*)bp, sizeof(double)); bp += sizeof(double);
  memcpy((void*)readData[i].Arr1, (void*)bp, ArraySize * sizeof(double)); bp += ArraySize * sizeof(double);
 memcpy((void*)readData[i].Arr2, (void*)bp, ArraySize * sizeof(double)); bp += ArraySize * sizeof(double);
}
```

And I'd like to optimize to vector field instead of array so I do not need malloc or even memcpy

```
typedef struct {
    double param1, param2;   // 1x1
    std::vector<double> arr1, arr2;      // 1xN
}myStruct
// no need for malloc...

for (i = 0; i < StructSize; i++){
  memcpy((void*)&readData[i].Param1, (void*)bp, sizeof(double)); bp += sizeof(double);
  memcpy((void*)&readData[i].Param2, (void*)bp, sizeof(double)); bp += sizeof(double);
  
  *** how to use std::copy to copy contents ??***
}
```

I have tried

```
std::copy(bp, bp + ArraySize * sizeof(double),std::back_inserter(readData[i].Arr1)); bp += ArraySize * sizeof(double);
std::copy(bp, bp + ArraySize * sizeof(double), std::back_inserter(readData[i].Arr2)); bp += ArraySize * sizeof(double);
```

But error out...

Can anyone points me to where I have made mistake?

Thanks

Comment: If `bp` has the correct alignment, `auto const src = reinterpret_cast<double const*>(bp); readData[i].Arr1 = std::vector<double>(src, src + ArraySize);` may do the trick (i.e. using overload (5) here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector )

Comment: thanks, @fabian    since I have a structure array,for (i = 0; i < StructSize; i++){} does this happened inside the for loop? then is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: @fabian   errored out for the second line: 
`auto const src = reinterpret_cast<double const*>(bp); 
rdata[i].f_eig_real = std::vector<double>(src, src + ArrDim);`

Comment: `double* pd = reinterpret_cast<double*>(bp); readData[i].arr1.assign(pd, pd + ArraySize); pd += ArraySize; readData[i].arr2.assign(pd, pd + ArraySize); pd += ArraySize; bp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pd);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you  But I got error when loop to `readData[i].arr1.assign(pd, pd + ArraySize)`   Error msg: Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Pnext was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: nvm, I have found the root cause for the access violation exception: it was caused by I was malloc for readData struct 'readData = (readData*)malloc(StructSize*size(double))`, use new has solved issue